# Named template parameters via encapsulation

Tags: c++, templates

I've been wondering if there is any solution for named template parameters in C++. For ordinary calls there are "Named Parameters Idiom", "Boost::Parameter library" and several more workarounds (for example these [these](https://marcoarena.wordpress.com/2014/12/16/bring-named-parameters-in-modern-cpp/)), but when One have ten-parameter template - the best and seems to be the only option is [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

In some Javascript guides I've seen the encapsulation technique: a set of parameters/arguments is represented as an object with default entries. The entries (parameters) become set by being overloaded (overwritten).

The useful side effect is that string literals, floating point values and other non-integral template parameters become easy-to-pass in this way.

For example:

```
struct DefSets {
  using Type                               = void*;
  static const int N                       = 10;
  constexpr static const double Ratio      = 2.5;
  constexpr static const char* Description = "Default";
};

template<class Settings = DefSets>
class ALotOfParametersClass { /* ... */ };

//----------------------------------------------------

struct MySets : public DefSets {
  constexpr static const char* Description = "Some text";
  constexpr static const double Ratio      = 3.5;
};

int main()
{
  ALotOfParametersClass<MySets> myInstance;
}
```

This is completely applicable to C++, yet I have never seen it in use (or even mentioned).

The questions are:

- What hidden obstacles/disadvantages could there be?
- Does this technique look fine after all?

Comment: I think in case of one wish specialization of the class according to some hidden parameter value the only way would be to use sfinae mechanism, while in case of tuple it would be really straightforward (pattern matching)...

Comment: It is used. Except it's called "traits classes".